# Installing one specific package using npm or yarn results on a socket timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, rhel8, mui-x-data-grid

`npm install @mui/icons-material`

I can install all other libraries with no issues, I have reached out to the networking team and they claim to have nothing in place regarding the npm repository.

```
202 silly audit '@mui/icons-material': [ '5.11.16' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/material': [ '5.11.16' ]
202 silly audit react: [ '18.2.0' ]
202 silly audit 'react-dom': [ '18.2.0' ]
202 silly audit '@babel/runtime': [ '7.21.0' ]
202 silly audit 'regenerator-runtime': [ '0.13.11' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/base': [ '5.0.0-alpha.124' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/core-downloads-tracker': [ '5.11.16' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/system': [ '5.11.16' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/types': [ '7.2.3' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/utils': [ '5.11.13' ]
202 silly audit '@types/react-transition-group': [ '4.4.5' ]
202 silly audit clsx: [ '1.2.1' ]
202 silly audit csstype: [ '3.1.2' ]
202 silly audit 'prop-types': [ '15.8.1' ]
202 silly audit 'react-is': [ '18.2.0'
'16.13.1' ]
202 silly audit 'react-transition-group': [ '4.4.5' ]
202 silly audit '@emotion/is-prop-valid': [ '1.2.0' ]
202 silly audit '@popperjs/core': [ '2.11.7' ]
202 silly audit '@emotion/memoize': [ '0.8.0' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/private-theming': [ '5.11.13' ]
202 silly audit '@mui/styled-engine': [ '5.11.16' ]
202 silly audit '@emotion/cache': [ '11.10.7' ]
202 silly audit '@emotion/sheet': [ '1.2.1' ]
202 silly audit '@emotion/utils': [ '1.2.0' ]
202 silly audit '@emotion/weak-memoize': [ '0.3.0' ]
202 silly audit stylis: [ '4.1.3' ]
202 silly audit '@types/prop-types': [ '15.7.5' ]
202 silly audit '@types/react-is': [ '17.0.3' ]
202 silly audit '@types/react': [ '18.0.34' ]
202 silly audit '@types/scheduler': [ '0.16.3' ]
202 silly audit 'loose-envify': [ '1.4.0' ]
202 silly audit 'object-assign': [ '4.1.1' ]
202 silly audit 'js-tokens': [ '4.0.0' ]
202 silly audit scheduler: [ '0.23.0' ]
202 silly audit 'dom-helpers': [ '5.2.1' ] 202 silly audit } 203 silly tarball no local data for @mui/icons-material@https://registry.npmjs.org/@mui/icons-material/-/icons-material-5.11.16.tgz. Extracting by manifest. 204 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 510ms 
205 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 516ms 
206 silly audit report {} 
207 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms 
208 timing reify:audit Completed in 517ms 
209 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/core-downloads-tracker Completed in 536ms 
210 timing reifyNode:node_modules/object-assign Completed in 541ms 
211 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/prop-types Completed in 540ms 
212 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/scheduler Completed in 554ms
213 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/react-is Completed in 554ms 
214 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/types Completed in 553ms 
215 timing reifyNode:node_modules/js-tokens Completed in 558ms 
216 timing reifyNode:node_modules/regenerator-runtime Completed in 592ms 
217 timing reifyNode:node_modules/loose-envify Completed in 597ms 
218 timing reifyNode:node_modules/clsx Completed in 597ms 
219 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/react-transition-group Completed in 636ms 
220 timing reifyNode:node_modules/prop-types/node_modules/react-is Completed in 637ms 
221 timing reifyNode:node_modules/react-is Completed in 640ms 
222 timing reifyNode:node_modules/prop-types Completed in 701ms 
223 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/react Completed in 704ms 
224 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@emotion/memoize Completed in 715ms 
225 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@emotion/weak-memoize Completed in 718ms 
226 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@emotion/utils Completed in 817ms 
227 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@emotion/sheet Completed in 829ms 
228 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@emotion/is-prop-valid Completed in 839ms 
229 timing reifyNode:node_modules/scheduler Completed in 888ms 
230 timing reifyNode:node_modules/stylis Completed in 886ms 
231 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@emotion/cache Completed in 975ms 
232 timing reifyNode:node_modules/react Completed in 1043ms 
233 timing reifyNode:node_modules/react-transition-group Completed in 1212ms 
234 timing reifyNode:node_modules/csstype Completed in 1225ms 
235 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/private-theming Completed in 1246ms 
236 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/styled-engine Completed in 1251ms 
237 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@babel/runtime Completed in 1740ms 
238 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/utils Completed in 1979ms 
239 timing reifyNode:node_modules/react-dom Completed in 2240ms 
240 timing reifyNode:node_modules/dom-helpers Completed in 2366ms 
241 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@popperjs/core Completed in 2697ms 
242 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/system Completed in 2815ms 
243 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/base Completed in 4741ms 
244 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/material Completed in 8892ms 
245 verbose stack Error: Socket timeout 245 verbose stack at TLSSocket.onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:346:23) 
245 verbose stack at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35) 
245 verbose stack at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:570:8) 
245 verbose stack at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17) 245 verbose stack at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) 
246 verbose cwd /data/nodejsprojects/jordan/testing 
247 verbose Linux 4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64 
248 verbose node v18.14.2 
249 verbose npm v9.6.4 
250 error code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT 
251 error network Socket timeout 
252 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity. 
252 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. 
252 error network 
252 error network If you are behind a proxy
please make sure that the 
252 error network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
253 verbose exit 1 
254 timing npm Completed in 1212820ms 
255 verbose unfinished npm timer command:install 1681189509954 
256 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1681189509961 
257 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:unpack 1681189510921 
258 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@mui/icons-material 1681189510926 259 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:rollback:createSparse 1681190722680 
260 verbose code 1 
261 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/jboncz/.npm/_logs/2023-04-11T05_05_09_872Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried multiple boxes to install the library, all the Linux boxes are encountering the error while all windows based machines can install it.

I have tried spinning up a brand new no base rhel image and installed npm and nodejs. Same issue occurred.

Networking team and midrange team are either being lazy, or really don't know where to start.

There is no proxy. Base npm settings work installing all other libraries

Comment: Try to include information in the question that will actually make it possible to determine the issue. Seeing a generic error and reading about why your network team won't fix it isn't very substantial.

Comment: What information do you think would provide more context? This is all the Informstion I have to go off. Says that it's a proxy issue in the error message, but we don't use a proxy. I have a feeling it has something to do with the sheer amount of files that are included in the library, hoping that someone else has run into a similar issue. I have included all the error logs I know to look for.

Comment: Every single post regarding this error I dictates that it's an issue installing all packages, whereas mine is installing a single very specific package. I have gone down the rabbit hole and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Are you running `npn` or `npm`?

Comment: Using `npm`, apologies. I have also attempted to use yarn to install the library as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer ended up being on the networking side. The firewall had a threshold limit for Palo Alto's packet lengths. The default limit is set for 4096 'loops' but in this case the library itself was over 20,000 individual items.

Once I was able to narrow down the issue, I engaged the networking team to change the upper threshold. Issue has been resolved.

See: https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA14u000000oNNICA2 for more information